# Insertar registros en forma de tabla

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Buen tarde,

Estoy trabajando en un sistema de restaurante en C# usando Windows Forms, el cual esta es la parte de tomar la orden:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero lograr en insertar esta orden en forma de tabla en SQL SERVER En la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y como quiero que se vea al insertarlo dentro de SQL es de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
 private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand agregar = new SqlCommand("Insert into Ordenes2 values (@Pedido, @Mesa, @NombreP, @Costo,@Fecha, @Hora)", cadena);

            try
            {
                cadena.Open();
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pedido", variables.orden);
                    agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mesa", label1.Text);
                    agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NombreP",Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value));

                    agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Costo", Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells[1].Value));
                    label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha",label2.Text);
                    agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hora", label3.Text);

                    agregar.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Orden tomada exitosamente");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al agregar " + ex);
            }

            finally
            {
                cadena.Close();
            }
        }
```

Pero tengo un problema, ¿donde debo de acomodar el ExecuteNonQuery? ya que me marca : **El nombre de las variables ya ha sido declarado.** Es por el ciclo pero no se en que parte colocarlo para que no de ese error.

Saludos, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Ezequie, tienes algun avance de lo que haz intentado?

Comment: Donde tienes el problema? deberias mostrar el codigo, y especificar donde especificamente esta el problema. Asi como esta, la pregunta puede ser cerrada.

Comment: Muestra el codigo con imagenes es mas dificil

Comment: Listo disculpen creí que si lo había agregado, ya lo corregí. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Debes crear un `procedimiento almacenado` de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GuardarOrden
    @Pedido INT, @Mesa VARCHAR(20), @NombreP VARCHAR(20), @Costo FLOAT, @Fecha DATE, @Hora TIME
AS
BEGIN
    Insert into Ordenes2 values (@Pedido, @Mesa, @NombreP, @Costo,@Fecha, @Hora)
END
GO
```

y en c#

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cadena = new SqlConnection();
        try
        {
            cadena.Open();
            SqlCommand agregar = new SqlCommand("SP_GuardarOrden", cadena);
            agregar.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pedido", variables.orden);
                agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mesa", label1.Text);
                agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NombreP", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value));
                agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Costo", Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells[1].Value));
                label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", label2.Text);
                agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hora", label3.Text);
                agregar.ExecuteNonQuery();
                agregar.Parameters.Clear();
            }
            agregar.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show("Orden tomada exitosamente");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al agregar " + ex);
        }

        finally
        {
            cadena.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nunca había trabajado con procedimientos almacenados, muchas gracias voy a utilizarlo. Saludos

Comment: Que mania de crear procedimientos para todo, es un simple insert!

Comment: Si no te gusta no lo hagas, a mi no me gusta agregar querys dentro del código es horrible y siempre intento evitarlo. Ya si es tu manera de trabajar hazlo, mas no critiques la mía. Y se llama programación modular, a la hora de querer cambiar el query no necesito compilar ni volver a publicar la solución, solo voy a mi BD y modifico el query es por eso que lo hago.

Answer (score 2):

Muchas Gracias por tomarse un poco del tiempo para leer mi inquietud logre insertarlo de la siguiente manera:

Agregue la linea: **agregar.Parameters.Clear();** La cual hace que en cada pasada de foreach los parametros queden libres.

```
 private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand agregar = new SqlCommand("Insert into Ordenes2 values (@Pedido, @Mesa, @NombreP, @Costo,@Fecha, @Hora)", cadena);

                try
                {
                    cadena.Open();
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                    {
                    agregar.Parameters.Clear();
                        agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pedido", variables.orden);
                        agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mesa", label1.Text);
                        agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NombreP", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value));

                        agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Costo", Convert.ToSingle(row.Cells[1].Value));
                        label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                        agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", label2.Text);
                        agregar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hora", label3.Text);

                        agregar.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show("Orden tomada exitosamente");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error al agregar " + ex);
                }

                finally
                {
                    cadena.Close();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Cual es la diferencia con el codigo original?

Comment: No tenia idea, que tenia que limpiar los parametros en cada pasada del Foreach:    agregar.Parameters.Clear();

Comment: `agregar.Dispose();` en cada iteración es lo que debías hacer al final de cada insert

Comment: Justo estaba agregandote una respuesta respuesto a eso, y ademas con otros tips, ya que tu codigo por lo que estas haciendo podria mejorar un poco mas.. pero si lo resolviste, esta perfecto. Y por favor aclara en la respuesta que fue lo que hiciste.

Comment: @VictorPerdomo no por dios.. si hace eso se queda sin query en la primer vuelta...

Comment: Muchas Gracias @gbianchi de igual forma si me puedes dar los tips aprendería mas. Saludos.

Comment: Si tienes razón bueno solo debe crear el command otra vez en cada iteración también

Comment: @VictorPerdomo tampoco es totalmente innecesario... Miren la respuesta que voy a agregar en 2 minutos...

Answer (score 2):

agregar es de tipo `SqlCommand`, lo cual esta perfecto. Tu código en realidad no tiene ninguna falla salvo por un minimo detalle.

El `SqlCommand`, la primera vuelta, agrega parametros a su coleccion Parameters (lo cual haces correctamente).

Pero luego de ejecutar la consulta, la misma no borra su contenido. Por lo cual, la colección de parámetros sigue teniendo los que agregaste.. y cuando pegas la vuelta, intentas agregar el mismo parametro que ya metiste antes, con un nuevo valor.. y no es asi como funciona.

Tu solucion es simple, limpia la coleción parámetros antes de pegar la vuelta.

Para ello, basta con agregar un `agregar.Parameters.Clear();` despues del `agregar.ExecuteNonQuery();`.

Igual, aparte de esto, yo te recomendaria preparar la consulta antes en este caso, porque estas haciendo siempre el mismo query y pasandole los mismos parametros.

Para ello, solo hay que cambiar un poco el código:

```
usign (SqlCommand agregar = new SqlCommand("Insert into Ordenes2 values (@Pedido, @Mesa, @NombreP, @Costo,@Fecha, @Hora)", cadena))
{
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Pedido", 0));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Mesa", 0));
    (etc)....
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        command.Parameters["@Pedido"].Value = variables.orden;
        command.Parameters["@Mesa"].Value = label1.Text;
        (etc)...
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

### Notas

El using, evita que tengas que hacer un dispose del comando al terminar, lo hace automaticamente.
No es necesario abrir la conexion con anticipacion, el command la abre automaticamente. Si tenes que cerrarla, y hacer el dispose correspondiente.

Comment: Excelente se ve mas limpio el código, muchas gracias por el consejo. Saludos.

Comment: Tenías razón se ve mucho mejor.